# How to make ConvertTo-Json not remove backslashes?

Tags: json, powershell

For this JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "Wildcard":  "**\\\\*.Tests*.dll"   
    }
]
```

When I use ConvertFrom-Json on this file I get this:

```
Wildcard                       : **\\*.Tests*.dll
```

Note that it removed two of the backslashes from the original. I want powershell to keep these backslashes, so that when I output the powershell object back to a file using `ConvertTo-Json`, I see the 4 backslashes in the JSON.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you done the `ConvertTo-Json` and verified that they are not there? That should be a part of the escaping that is performed when it converts it to JSON. That is exactly the behavior when I tested it on my end.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I was doing a separate unescape elsewhere in code that I didn't include here.

Answer (score 2):

there is a function to unescape the 4 special characters like bashslashes

```
ConvertTo-Json | % { [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Unescape($_) }
```

Comment: This works perfectly. This answer explained in English: pass the entire JSON string to forEach (alias = %) and unescape it using the class `[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex` which has the method `Unescape`